# How to remove some landuse classes from a dataset?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have the following dataset and would like to remove everything but forests and grasslands.
Can someone please help me understand how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can do this using the raster calculator, converting Forest and Grassland to 1, the rest to 0, which gives you a mask.

Comment: This is likely a tasks better solved with symbology settings, rather than data manipulation. Just remove the respective values from the renderer (or set the symbol color to be fully transparent, or white).

Comment: I would like to remove the other classes altogether.. if that is possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove values from a raster. You can recalculate them or set them to nodata:

Warp twice and set nodata value. For example if I want to "remove" value 2:

[image]